# Vim any character replaced by itself

Tags: regex, vim

In Vim, a search and replace command which to the segment below:

```
func {print("touching curly braces")}
```

transforms it into this:

```
func { print("touching curly brace") }
```

So far I have:

```
:%s/{.\( \)\@!/{./g
```

However, it does this to the first segment:

```
func {.rint("touching curly braces")}
```

I believe I need something like this:

```
:%s/{.\( \)\@!/{ ./g
:%s/}.\( \)\@!/} ./g
```

How do I replace the kleene star '.' with the character it matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `.` into  a group so you can repeat in the substituion string `\(.\)`

```
:%s/{\(.\)\( \)\@!/{ \1/g
:%s/}\(.\)\( \)\@!/} \1/g
```

This is what is called **backreferencing** and **grouping**

If you want to do both spaces at once here is the command:

```
:%s/{\(\S.*\S\)}/{ \1 }/g
```

Comment: That second line you provided is exactly what I was hoping to make, thanks. I just took Tomalak's wise suggestion to use /gc to review the various cases before accepting the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace

```
:%s/{\($| \)\@!/{ /g
```

and

```
:%s/\(^| \)\@<!}/ }/g
```

where `{\($| \)\@!` is `{` and a [negative lookahead](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@!) for either end-of-line or space, the other expression is analogous with a [negative lookbehind](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@<!) and `}`.

Note that replacing in source code like that is a dangerous endeavor. You can break things very easily. Think of curly braces inside strings, or in regular expressions, or other situations you did not quite think of. Use `/gc` instead of `/g` to manually confirm each change.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean this? I hope I understood your problem right:

```
s/\zs{\ze./& /g
s/.\zs}\ze/ &/g
```

You can do it in this way too:

```
s/{\ze./& /g
s/.\zs}/ &/g
```